# pandas boolean indexing of dataframe in dictionary of data frames

Tags: pandas, dictionary, for-loop, boolean-indexing

So, this is probably a really simple problem, but I've not found a solution yet. I apologize for my stupidity. (I'm guessing my ignorance of terminology has impeded my searching here)

I have a dictionary of dataframes (showing 2 in here, but it contains more).

```
    df_dict={'P1': df0,'P2': df1}
```

Each dataframe may or may not have rows that I need to remove for further processing. I can easily remove these rows from one dataframe like so:

```
    df0=df_dict['P1']
    df0=df0[df0.well !='1']
```

But if I loop through the dictionary like this, nothing happens. The unwanted rows are still in the dataframes.

```
    for key,df in df_dict.items():
        df=df[df.well !='1']
```

I stupidly plunked `inplace=True` into the `.loc` and obviously that didn't work. 
Side note, I can't do `df[~df.well.str.contains('1')]` because this would remove rows that have correct positions like `'A01'`

Again, I'm probably doing something very ignorant, and am very grateful for your help!

Comment: Could you please add the sample dataframes and required outputs, so that error can be reproduced

Comment: Sorry Ashwin, I decided to work on something else for a while. When I came back to this Vijay (below) had given me a perfect fix! Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the 'for loop' to as mentioned below :

```
for key,df in df_dict.items():
    df_dict[key]=df[df.well !='1']
```

This should fix the issue.